# Установка шрифтов

Tags: c#, vb.net, шрифты

Здраствуйте. Я в проекте использую не стандартные шрифты. У себя их добавлял вручную (Панель инструментов -> Шрифты). Но мне нужно автоматизировать процесс и получить работоспособную программу в `Windows XP - 7` . Как поступают в таких случаях?

Comment: Да, IDE уточните. А то мало ли что вы там используете. Я написал вариант для Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я ничего не путаю, то в таких случаях добавляют шрифты в сам проект, причем, в его установщик. Там вроде даже специальная папка под шрифты должна быть.

Статья про это [раз](http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2009/03/26/Installing-and-removing-fonts-using-C.aspx). (тут случай с добавлением special folder. Знание английского required)

Если не помогло, то читаем [два](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms753303.aspx). (эта на русском, но решение для WPF. Может поможет.)

Comment: @Olter , IDE - VS2008 , Можете пожалуйста подсказать как их добавить ?